# How long does it take for this sequence to obtain this loop?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

For positive integers $m,n$, define a sequence $S_m(n)$ so that $S_m(1)=m$, $S_m(n+1)=S_m(n)^2-1$ if $S_m(n)$ is prime, and $S_m(n+1)$ is the greatest prime factor of $S_m(n)$ otherwise. It is clear that, regardless of $m$, this sequence always gets caught in the infinite loop $2,3,8,2,3,\dots$, because for any prime $p$, $p^2-1=(p+1)(p-1)$ and if $p\neq 2$ then the greatest prime factor of this term is at most $\lceil p/2\rceil<p$.

What is less clear, is the rate at which the sequence becomes stuck into that loop. If we define $t(m)$ to be the smallest integer $n$ so that $S_m(n)=2$, then how does $t(m)$ grow? By some numerical testing I've found that $t(m)<20$ for all $m<10000$, which seems to suggest a logarithmic growth speed. In particular, for any positive integer $N$, is it always true that there exists an $m$ so that $t(m)>N$? Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: nice question, but I couldn't help but laugh at "which seems to suggest a logarithmic growth speed", not in a rude way, but I just used to be very convinced by code output for small input values, which I've learned is a very bad habit. I'll think about this nice question

Comment: @mathworker21: Haha, thanks. I wanted to have my computer run more values and plot the graph to see graphically how $t$ grows like, but wasn't able to do so---I think due to CPU limitations. I'll try again soon and will edit it in here if it successfully leads to some insight.

Comment: studying $t(m)$ seems silly. you should instead look at $\tilde{t}(M) := \max_{1 \le m \le M} t(m)$

Comment: Well, if you have a way to make that work, I'm all ears. Nothing I've tried got me far as yet.

Comment: make what work? $t(m)$ varies drastically with $m$, so there's no way to study it. there might be a better chance of analyzing $\tilde{t}(M)$. Either way, the main problem here (to me at least) is whether $t(m)$ is unbounded (equivalently, whether $\tilde{t}(M)$ is unbounded)

Comment: Also, I think you should redefine $S_m$. For a prime $m$, $S_m(1) = m$ and $S_m(n+1)$ is the largest prime factor of $(S_m(n)-1)(S_m(n)+1)$. It only changes the growth rate of $t(m)$ by at most a multiplicative factor of $2$, and is much conceptually easier. I think it might actually be hard to show $t(m)$ is unbounded, but I don't have a proof (e.g. $t(m)$ unbounded implies RH). I'll come back

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! If you suspect that more *can* be said, I will happily sponsor another round. May be let it rest for a while, and return to it later?

Comment: @Jyrki: Sure, that would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

Recording the following observation to get the ball rolling.

Assume that $\ell>2$ is a [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime), in other words, a prime such that $p=2\ell+1$ is also a prime. In that case
$$
(p+1)(p-1)=(2\ell+2)\cdot2\ell=2^3\cdot\frac{\ell+1}2\ell
$$
implying that $\ell$ is the largest prime factor of $p^2-1$. So if $S_m(n)=p$ then $S_m(n+2)=\ell$.

A Cunningham chain of length $k$ is a sequence of iterated Sophie Germain primes
$$p_1<p_2<p_3<\cdots<p_k$$
such that $p_{i+1}=2p_i+1$ for all $i$. For example, $5<11<23<47$ is Cunningham sequence of length $4$. Iterating the argument of the previous paragraph tells us that if $S_m(n)=p_k$ for some $m,n$, then $S_m(n+2(k-1))=p_1$. This implies that if a Cunngham chain of length $k$ exists, then it takes about $2k$ steps for your sequence to come down to $p_1$.

According to the cited Wikipedia page it is an open conjucture that arbitrarily long Cunningham chains exist. In light of the above that conjecture would imply that the function $t$ is unbounded.

---

Of course, there is no need to have longer and longer Cunningham chains for $t$ to be unbounded. I just felt that this connection may be interesting. It is, of course, easy to show that the set of prime factors of numbers of the form $p^2-1$ is unbounded, but I couldn't see how unboundedness of $t$ would follow from such a simple fact.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. I haven't thought of the connection to Cunningham chains before.

Comment: To be honest, I'm a bit disappointed about my inability to prove that $t$ is undounded. It should (?) be possible to prove that a large enough class of primes appears as values of $S_m(3)$, inductively argue that the set of values of $S_m(2k+1)$ is not bounded for any $k$, but... no cigar.